# Read Integers and count them, then rewind---C

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, fseek

this is a small piece of my homework that I am having difficulty with. There is more to the function then this part but this is all that I am having difficulty with(There is more after). When I run this, it tells me that it failed to read the integer file. Can anyone tell me where I should start looking on where I went wrong?

```
int * readIntegers(const char * filename, int * numberOfIntegers)
{

  FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");  
 int count = 0;
// int array;
 if(fp== NULL)
   {
     return NULL;
   }
 while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &count)>0)
   {
     (*numberOfIntegers)++;
   }
 printf("%d\n",*numberOfIntegers);
```

Compiler warnings, I am not concerned about these since they don't have to do with that I posted

```
warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
 warning: unused variable ‘array’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

And when it runs this is what I get...

```
./pa03 inputs/input0 > outputs/output0    ./pa03 inputs/input0 > outputs/output0
Failed to read integer-file 'inputs/input0', aborting
cat outputs/output0
Failed to read integer-file 'inputs/input0', aborting
cat outputs/output0
```

Also, the print statement towards the end was diagnostic, later in the function I will return an array that will display the answer. I was trying to see if the numberOfInputs got updated to the correct number, which has not happened so far. I will update my print statemnet to see if it works...will update.

Here is the entire log now.

> gcc -g -Wall -Wshadow -c -o obj/answer03.o answer03.c answer03.c: In
>   function ‘readIntegers’: answer03.c:85:2: warning: return from
>   incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] answer03.c:85:2:
>   warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by
>   default] answer03.c:68:6: warning: unused variable ‘array’
>   [-Wunused-variable] gcc -g -Wall -Wshadow -c -o obj/pa03.o pa03.c gcc
>   -g -Wall -Wshadow obj/answer03.o obj/pa03.o  -o pa03
>
> ./pa03 inputs/input0 > outputs/output0
>   *** glibc detected *** ./pa03: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff9ffebad0 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x2acd35b25b96]
>   ./pa03[0x400c67]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x2acd35ac876d]
>   ./pa03[0x400699]
>   ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1443970
>   /home/matt/ECE264/solutions/PA03/pa03 00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000
>   08:06 1443970
>   /home/matt/ECE264/solutions/PA03/pa03 00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000
>   08:06 1443970
>   /home/matt/ECE264/solutions/PA03/pa03 0219f000-021c0000 rw-p 00000000
>   00:00 0                                  [heap]
>   2acd35882000-2acd358a4000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 8130309
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so 2acd358a4000-2acd358a9000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  2acd35aa4000-2acd35aa5000 r--p 00022000 08:06
>   8130309                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
>   2acd35aa5000-2acd35aa7000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 8130309
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so 2acd35aa7000-2acd35c5c000 r-xp
>   00000000 08:06 8127294
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 2acd35c5c000-2acd35e5b000 ---p
>   001b5000 08:06 8127294
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 2acd35e5b000-2acd35e5f000 r--p
>   001b4000 08:06 8127294
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 2acd35e5f000-2acd35e61000 rw-p
>   001b8000 08:06 8127294
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 2acd35e61000-2acd35e68000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  2acd35e68000-2acd35e7d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06
>   8130119                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>   2acd35e7d000-2acd3607c000 ---p 00015000 08:06 8130119
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 2acd3607c000-2acd3607d000 r--p
>   00014000 08:06 8130119
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 2acd3607d000-2acd3607e000 rw-p
>   00015000 08:06 8130119
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7fff9ffcd000-7fff9ffee000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
>   7fff9ffff000-7fffa0000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vdso] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
>   [vsyscall] ./bin/test.sh: line 20:  8797 Aborted                 (core
>   dumped) ./$EXEC $INF > $OUTF cat outputs/output0
>
> 5    Unsorted array:  35254288   0  194   5 -1610695872    Sorted
>   array:    35254289   5 -1610695984   1 -1610695872 -- FAIL (not
>   sorted).    Integer '35254288' not found -- FAIL.    Integer
>   '35254289' not found -- FAIL.
>
> Checking expected output: expected/expected0 - FAIL. Expected:
>
> Unsorted array:   4   1   3   2   5    Sorted array:     1   2   3 
>   4   5 -- correct.    Integer '4' in the 3th position in the sorted
>   array -- pass.    Integer '5' in the 4th position in the sorted array
>   -- pass.
>
> make: *** [test0] Error 1

Test case:
4
1
3
2
5

Comment: Where's the part where it tells you it failed to read the integer file?

Comment: You might change that "%n" in the printf to "%d".

Comment: See Jonathan's answer below. %n is very weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf("%n", numberOfIntegers)` call will write a zero into the integer pointed to by `numberOfIntegers`.  That's because there are zero characters written before the `%n` format is interpreted (see the specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)).

Probably, you wanted to use:

```
printf("%d\n", *numberOfIntegers);
```

---

### An SSCCE

Here is an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) closely based on the code shown in the question that demonstrates that there is nothing horribly wrong with that code  — and hence that the problems encountered in the question are in code that is not shown.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static
int *readIntegers(const char *filename, int *numberOfIntegers)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int count;
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &count) > 0)
    {
        (*numberOfIntegers)++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", *numberOfIntegers);
    fclose(fp);
    return numberOfIntegers;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *file = "data";
    int num = 0;
    int *p;
    if (argc > 1)
        file = argv[1];
    p = readIntegers(file, &num);
    if (p != &num)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read numbers from file %s\n", file);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Number of numbers in file %s is %d\n", file, num);
    return 0;
}
```

Given a file called `data` containing:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Or the equivalent file with each blank replaced by a newline, the output of the program is:

```
11
Number of numbers in file data is 11
```

If the program is called `ri` (*Read Integers*), and is called as:

```
$ ./ri missing
Failed to read numbers from file missing
$
```

In neither case does it crash.  I added the code to close the file and return the input pointer.  This code compiles cleanly on Mac OS X 10.8.4 using GCC 4.8.1 with the command line set to extremely stringent:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition ri.c -o ri
$
```

So, as stated, the problem is not directly in the code fragment presented to us for scrutiny.

The compiler warnings that you are ignoring really worry me precisely because they point to problems that will manifest themselves after the code shown successfully executes.  Returning a pointer to a local variable is a way to crash programs; returning the wrong type of pointer from a function is a way to crash programs.  (I'll grant you that the unused variable warning is about as benign as they get — I am not worried about that one, though by commenting out the declaration, you've prevented it from appearing.)

So, you need to present more program for anyone to diagnose successfully your problem.  What you show is OK code.

Comment: When I change the code posted in the OP to that print statement, I get a seg fault

Comment: Since you don't show how the 'failed to read' message is being generated, we can't help you until you do show us the call to this function and the code that is generating the error message.  As to the seg-fault, did you change both the format string and the use of `numberOfIntegers`?  I'm assuming that you have `int *numberOfIntegers` as a parameter to the function. Please see how to create an an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: I have updated my post, and will also update with the first input I test.

Comment: We seem to be dealing with a moving target.  Please reproduce the problem in a small program so we can help.  The crash now shown in the  question does not obviously relate to the code asked about in the question.  It might be that the compiler warnings are mattering (the incorrect return and returning address of local variable warnings matter unless the code is crashing in the function, which is not shown clearly in the example code).  We cannot debug your code if we can't see it.  You should only show us the minimum code, but it should compile (cleanly) and reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can also add `fflush(0)` to ensure that the output is printed to standard output.  Basically, either step through the code in the debugger, or lace it with `printf()` statements so that you can see exactly where it is failing.

Comment: The end result of the program is that it displays the unsorted array, then displays the sorted array. As in, the file system we have set up takes what I return and compares it against what the output should be and determines if it is a pass or a fail. The only thing I return from my function is the sorted array. Everything showing in the code up there is all that compiles. I know that my issue is in the while loop with the fscanf, so I guess if you could look at that and if you see anything weird about it tell me? sorry that I made this so unclear

Comment: @Liquidmetal: see the SSCCE in the answer.  The problem is not in the code you have shown; it is, therefore, in the code you have not shown: either the call to `ReadIntegers()` is faulty, or the material in the function after — or before — the fragment shown is faulty, or both.

Comment: Thank you so much. You really went out of the way for me, wish I could do something more then just vote up and checkmark! ANd thanks for the example SSCCE